# az acr build dockerfile secret declaration

Tags: azure, dockerfile, docker-secrets

I am trying to pass secrets using build secret argument (values passed through github secrets) as mentioned in Microsoft documentation, how should I utilize these secrets in my dockerfile?
Currently I'm using ARG but looking at articles it isn't the best way.

Docker build:

az acr build -r $registry -f $resolvedDockerFilePath --platform $platform --image "$($Env:PROJECT_ENGAGEMENT):$($Env:DEPLOYMENT_VERSION)" --image "$($Env:PROJECT_ENGAGEMENT):latest" --secret-build-arg GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN="$githubApiKey" --secret-build-arg LW_AGENT_TOKEN="$ENV:LW_AGENT_ACCESS_TOKEN" .
}

I've tried using ARG in dockerfile but it exposes the secrets in layers.Looking at similar posts most of them mention secret mounting from a file, but I'm not using any file to pass secrets.

How these secrets should be consumed inside dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Facing a similar issue, the best option so far seems to be using Docker [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) so that secrets are not part of the layers published by the build.